# SqlBulkCopy Timeout when used within a WCF Sercive that sets TransactionScopeRequired

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, transactionscope, sqlbulkcopy

Situation:
WCF Service with TransactionScopeRequired OperationBehaviour.
WCF Service runs a process that used SqlBulkCopy to insert many rows to a db.

When used without the TransactionScopeRequired behaviour, the SqlBulkCopy inserts records with no issue, however when this behaviour is set to true, not even a small amount of records can be inserted.

Further info - The WCF Service uses a MSMQ Endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. It was late when I posted the above..:)

Following further analysis (I am ashamed to be writing this..!) the issue was due to the implementation of my service making use of the Task Processing Library - i.e. I had multiple processes making DB calls wrapped within a TransactionScope - for example -

-First process performs actions against DB.  This action appends a transaction to the transactionscopes transaction and caused a db lock.

-Second process is then spawned and attempts to write to the same table - it is unable to as the transaction is not part of the original transaction scope.

Solution - Some redesign will be required to provide smarter transaction management!